# Zend setting includePaths from config file

Tags: php, zend-framework, config, include-path

I have a zend 1.11 app.In the index.php file I have the following:

```
set_include_path(APPLICATION_PATH.'/library'.PATH_SEPARATOR.get_include_path());
```

And everything works.Now I want to set the include path from the config file, so I added in it:

```
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/library"
```

But if I remove the "set_include_path" from the index.php file I receive an error (library-classes are not found)..

How does it work the setting of the include path from config file?

Thanks

Luca

Answer (score 1):

Your path is wrong make sure you do like this

```
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
```

Comment: Now you can remove the set_include_path from your index file..will works like a charm :)

Comment: my paths are identical both in config and index.php file .One Works but not the other.Path is not wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.

`require_once 'Zend/Application.php';`
^ See this line? It requires the Zend Framework to be in your include path before even the config file is loaded.

Comment: I can't? so what's the usage of the includePaths.library line in config file? Btw in my index.php i have "
require_once APPLICATION_PATH.'/library/Zend/Application.php';"